# Randoming symbols from a-Z

Tags: sas

I need to generate a string from random characters in range of `a-Z`. How can i do it?

Atm, i can only suggest randoming numbers in range of `1-52` and then reinitialize numbers with charecters. But that sounds awful.

Comment: What's the relation between the title and the description?

Comment: @MarcCompte, i have fixed it,sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `byte` function, along with a random number, to generate a random character.  Just loop the desired number of times and combine the results with `call cats`.  The `byte` function returns the relevant character from the ASCII table.  For your example you need ASCII numbers 65-90 (A-Z) and 97-122 (a-z).  The following code will generate a random sequence of 6 characters.

```
data _null_;
length z $6 y $1;
do x=1 to 6;
    do until (rank(y) in (65:90,97:122)); /* ASCII characters A-Z, a-z */
    y=byte(65+floor((1+122-65)*rand("uniform"))); /* Generate random integer between 65 and 122 */
    end;
call cats(z,y); /* concatenate values */
end;
putlog z;
run;
```

Comment: Could you please explain, what the `4th` row does?

Comment: The 5th row returns a random number between 65 and 122. You don't want to include numbers 91-96 however, so the 4th row adds an extra loop that runs until the number returned isn't in that range.  The variable y actually stores the character values (this is what `byte` returns), so I have to use the `rank` function to convert it back to the ASCII number.

Answer (score 2):

CALL RANPERM seems well suited for this task.

```
25         data shuffle(keep=a: drop=addr);
26            array a[52] $1;
27            addr = addrlong(a1);
28            call pokelong(cat(collate(65,90),collate(97,122)),addr,52);
29            put @20 a[*];
30            seed=1234567890123;
31            do n=1 to 10;
32               call ranperm(seed,of a[*]);
33               put seed= @20 a[*];
34               output;
35               end;
36            stop;
37            run;

                   A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
seed=295748501     i U I K e d H R b E D k u N c v B M T Z G V n A s W h r q Q j F J o x X O p g t Y w z P C m S l L f a y
seed=766887342     z F v U N G M q u H P Q Z d y b X l a D f p Y w m o r V A B n J I j e g c S x R T K O L i s k C h E W t
seed=618158873     L v x k T r c m S e F w n Z K G P t q E W C h M z X p d N o H Y V i s Q u y f B J O g l U R D b I a j A
seed=632090736     J l H Y T R A p N x C v U b w K V W d X t L y E G o Q B M z I S n q k f s O F P D j a r m i c g Z h e u
seed=1911942895    t G j Z e K q H x m L F A g T h v W a y V C B M k I r J S R P s Y Q p w O D E l X U o z u N d f n i b c
seed=479260872     Y Q i d P R z S G B a D K Z X j M E b h T m c e C I n x y w o A k r U f H u l N W s v J p L q O t g V F
seed=1143672881    L X i f a u m K T g x p E M o B q Z s c t A Q I P G D z U d H S y V J F j h r e l v C b k Y W R O w N n
seed=869134054     F D U g G w A Y J o e p r b H z q d l I L M v R W h y m t S n V x T P C K B k O Q i j s c N f Z a X E u
seed=481233318     n h P j V M y S W s m F a G l q f d o O A u T I E p k z b e C X t v Q H i w c U g Z K B R N L x r D J Y
seed=1445828380    d P t o N h c R r M l n E y g F x z S a W L G p w T Q k B H e v I K i b f q X C m Y D J Z V j A U u O s
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to use direct memory access functions to do this? Seems like overkill.

Comment: DN, you might want to explain what `call ranperm` is doing here - i.e., it's 'shuffling' the letters, so sampling without replacement.

Comment: @user667489 I could have used a do loop to fill the array but as mentioned by this is easy way to accomplish the same result.  Overkill, I reckon I don't think so.

Comment: @Joe I thought RANPERM was self explanatory and there's this http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/69762/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p04f5b1sjxoeqjn1eyk1hxuyfrkb.htm

Comment: Probably worth noting that this is not equivalent to Keith's solution unless you only keep e.g. the first letter from each permutation - otherwise each letter will come up at most once. `call ranperk` might help with this.

Comment: @user667489 I know it is not equivalent to Keith's program which does not make a random permutation of the 52 items.  Keith's program appears to generate an unrestricted random sample which I don't think the OP wants even though it appears he does think so.

Comment: @data_null yes, that's a very valid point that I should have quantified in my answer.  It wasn't clear from the question whether the same character could appear more than once

Comment: @Keith I agree the question was rather vague.  Although mildly interesting as we got to use some cool functions.