# SAS Random array with a nonrecurrent elements

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Could you please help me.
I would like to generate a ***random array***  from 0 to 5 and I'm using this function

```
rand_num = int(ranuni(0)*5+1)
```

But I would like to generate a random array with a ***nonrecurrent*** elements.
For example `(1,2,3,4,5) (3,1,5,4,2)` etc..

How I can do it?
Thank You!

Comment: Also consider the answer from @data_null in this question.  `call randperm` is a good option for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42086988/randoming-symbols-from-a-z/42091012#42091012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* draw with repetition */
data a;
    array rand(5);

    do i = 1 to dim(rand);
        rand(i) = int(ranuni(0)*5+1);
    end;

    keep rand:;
run;

/* draw without repetition */
data a;
    array rand(5);

    do i = 1 to dim(rand);
        do until(rand(i) ^= .);
            value = int(ranuni(0)*5+1);
            if value not in rand then
                rand(i) = value;
        end;
    end;

    keep rand:;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `call ranperm` is the better solution for this, though both seem to have roughly the same statistical properties.  Here's a solution using that (very similar to what Keith pointed to in [@data_null_'s solution on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42086988/randoming-symbols-from-a-z/42091012#42091012)):

```
data want;
  array rand_array[5];

  *initialize the array (once);
  do _i = 1 to dim(rand_array);
    rand_array[_i]=_i;
  end;

  *seed for the RNG;
  seed=5;

  *randomize;
  *each time `call ranperm` is used, this shuffles the group;
  do _i = 1 to 1e5;
    call ranperm(seed,of rand_array[*]);
    output;
  end;
run;
```